# JavaScript error on blank line

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax-error

So I'm currently getting the following 2 errors on line 178 but lines 71 through 211 are all blank.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

Now the only `$` in the whole page, is in a piece of valid RegEx and on line 218 so there are 7 lines prior to it before it occurs. The if-statement could be anywhere so I'm not too sure on that.

```
<!-- line 71 -->

<!-- ... ->

<!-- line 211 -->
```

My site is using WordPress and this didn't start happening until I added a custom form. I however fixed all the errors it was causing but am still getting this 1 annoying error.

What causes the console to report errors on blank lines and how can I fix them?

EDIT: Stopped getting the first error and the code now works so I assume to was a caching issue (even though I emptied my cache). That second error is now on line 179

Comment: Does the console message say the error is in the page (.php) or in an external javascript file?

Comment: Is this on live ?Then I need to see this .. because there has to be something that is why it is giving an error.

Comment: @Jonsurrell It appears to be apart of the `<head>` tags still. I copied a fragment of the code here: http://pastebin.com/UTW80CWN

You should be able to tell where line 211 starts.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Not the problem. That line is printed like this:

`echo "<p>This doesn't have to be a confirmed champion or not. Could be any Marvel character. (1 Champion Only)</p>";`

Comment: @t.niese I know, that's why whenever jQuery is being used, `$` has been replaced with `jQuery` so as I said, the only `$` in the entire page is in a RegEx pattern.

Comment: Line 179 is the <script> for your poll.  Everything from 'This poll is completely anonymous' to just before the share links.  This is the error in that line: `var edit=if(edit===1)`

Comment: @Spedwards yes and I told you **why** it most likely was shown on an empty line and that this is also the reason **why**  you don't find any related `$` on the page.

Comment: I am flagging to close this. There is a simple syntactical error detectable on an offsite resource. No value is provided to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Line 179 is not blank on the source you showed. Specifically the `if` error is here:

```
var edit=if(edit===1){ //...
```